# Can ping but no DNS

Tags: dns

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. This laptop has a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 Wifi network card, but no ethernet port.

- I can connect to the router.
- I can ping to 8.8.8.8, but when opening google.com  I get "server not found" in Firefox.
- I can open websites by using their ip address.

I've opened the connection settings, changed the IPv4 method to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only". I've set DNS servers to 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4.

I've restarted the network:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Then I get:

```
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
```

So I rebooted to be sure, but no DNS.

How can I get DNS working?

Comment: Run `nslookup www.google.com`. The first line of the output should be the address of the DNS server that the system is trying to use. In your case, it should be 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 1):

You can set DNS server to the **/etc/resolv.conf** to check that there is no firewall or another issue.

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

And change your name server to 8.8.8.8

Comment: And this will be overwritten by Network Manager the next time the OP will boot. Don't touch this file if the configuration is done via Network Manager (if done via the GUI, it is likely to be done via Network Manager).

Comment: Yes, do it this way instead: https://askubuntu.com/a/1050280

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu Mate 17.04. I went to System -> Administration -> Network, selected DNS and added 8.8.8.8. That fixed it.