# No DNS names resolution in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, xubuntu, dns

The system is Xubuntu 14.04 on an S3J series Asus laptop.

It worked o.k. until it suddenly stopped resolving internet names. 
As I recall, it happened during an "apt-get upgrade" process.
First, I did not know what happened - I was unable to connect to any web page - and I thought I hit the ISP's monthly transfer limit (yeah ...).
But when I tried to research the issue (in a new transfer period), it appeared that the net connection is ok, but the system does not resolve host names.

I can ping any external internet address (ie. 104.16.19.44) but I cannot ping "askubuntu.com".

I tried to connect the computer to different networks:

- via a cable modem (the ISP mentioned)
- via vlan
- via gsm modem

and the problem persists in all of them.

And the network manager connection info dialog shows that the dns server addresses are provided through dhcp/ppp.

The /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts files look all right - no unexpected changes there.

The /etc/resolve.conf file contains the "127.0.1.1" entry - which is also normal with dnsmasq.

I have reinstalled dnsmasq-base and, after it giving no improvement, am stuck.

I can add that I have another Xubuntu 14.04 system on a desktop computer that has never had such a problem.

I would really appreciate any suggestion about what can be done before the system reinstall.

I have noticed my post is another one in a series of similar cases:

- [Ubuntu 14.04 no DNS resolv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599669/ubuntu-14-04-no-dns-resolv)
- [Can ping but no DNS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509703/can-ping-but-no-dns)

Unfortunately, so far there were no solution for the problem. Perhaps this time?