# 18.04: Bionic Beaver: enforce static /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: network-manager, dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

Previously, on Ubuntu 16.04, I felt betrayed when an Ubuntu update installed `dnsmasq` package, configured it, and gave it precedence over my own super-stable, ultra-fast, and own-configured BIND DNS server. It exactly felt as if Ubuntu hacked my workstation.

Since I happened to be working as a system admin, this was extremely unacceptable. This was a freak-out call. This is when you go to troubleshoot a problem and in one of your steps you use `dig` or `nslookup` and you get stunned to see the `lo` interface replying to you. *PANIC*

Is there a way to not only fix this issue, but also guarantee that `/etc/resolv.conf` will be tamper proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple edit to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and disabling `systemd-resolved.service`(as in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/907249/719422). But that alone, while essential, does not guarantee tamper-proof `resolv.conf`.

To really enforce a static `/etc/resolv.conf` that you know will survive restarts of any kind, you need to set the *immutable* attribute to it. Adding to the answer of Bastian Voigt mentioned above, you do this as SuperUser:

```
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf
chattr -e /etc/resolv.conf
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

...changing the `nameserver` to your chosen value. That way, you can have a *really* static `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: The /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file does not exist in 18.04

Comment: @hfranco if it does not, which I doubt, then you just create one! And, btw, if that is your case, then it is not a standard setup; your case is abnormal. I would say you mistyped while looking for it!

Comment: @hfranco As old as 12.04 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154338/not-see-file-networkmanager-conf-in-folder-etc-networkmanager

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, you can write your `resolv.conf` to `/usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf`, which is a static file that can be linked from `/etc/resolv.conf`. That should not be rewritten.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html#contenttoc3

> /ETC/RESOLV.CONF
>
> Four modes of handling /etc/resolv.conf (see resolv.conf(5)) are supported:
>
> ...
>
> A static file /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf is provided that lists the
> 127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as only DNS server. This file may be symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf in order to connect all local clients
> that bypass local DNS APIs to systemd-resolved. This file does not
> contain any search domains.

Comment: No, sorry. What happens when the spec changes or config method alters *on Ubuntu's own willing*? You know, this is the same fiasco I left Satya's corrupted dreams of an OS for. And, this is the same fiasco that Linux should be avoiding. What's wrong with resolve.conf? Why the hassle? Why try mimic the hateful and tedious Redhat network config, in some way or another? Sorry, I will only stick to my solution.

Comment: How do you know that your file wont simply be ignored in the future?  I know that forcing the static way some apps would work and others wont.  With wisbucky's solution, at least we can use the current way.  I didnt see the need for them to change it either but I didnt get a vote.  Someone downvoted this solution when in fact it does work and is the simplest. +1

Comment: @Marlon "How do you know that your file wont simply be ignored in the future"? Because it is set immutable; and, if /etc/resolv.conf is going to be ignored, so why the fuss anyway building a framework around it?? Ignoring the file will only happen if some Ubuntu wacko decided it is useless (implementing something into interfaces file, for example!)

Comment: If I wanted someone taking decisions for me, I would have gone back to the wacko Microsoft Windows, whose coders and designers and Satya above them all think they know your sake better than you do and that you have no right choosing how to run their "creation". Fuss!

Comment: Why the fuss build an OS for the good of mankind, if mankind cannot enjoy running it? What the fuss is Immutable attribute if someone is going to tell me when to use it or not. This is not about "following galactic manuals of Vega", this is about freedom of choice; no one should ever pose his own rigid single-minded impulse on you. You are a being and you have rights.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I've found is to prevent NetworkManager from updating /etc/resolv.conf and then creating a new /etc/resolv.conf file with a static DNS server. See https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/resolvconf-tutorial for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the spam! But you are missing the Immutable attribute, anyway!

Answer (score -2):

The file present is a symlink to another file.
Delete the file

```
rm /etc/resolve.conf
vim /etc resolve.conf
enter your data
:wq
```

The file is no longer a symlink but a persistent file.

Comment: Steps already direct to deleting /etc/resolv.conf beforehand.