# Cannot run software after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, software-center

Yesterday I decided to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. Soon enough I bumped into some issues, like no internet connectivity because of the `resolv.conf` being overwritten during the upgrade. I managed to fix that by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031279/18-04-bionic-beaver-enforce-static-etc-resolv-conf) link.

Still, I am having another issue: when I look under `Software & Updates`, under the `Other Software` tab, I see a bunch of disabled repos, hence I am not able to run or reinstall any new software.

Any help with this will be much appreciated. Is there a way to purge the repos so that I can keep running the installed software seemlessly? Or shall I reinstall the software anew? An example of this is Rednotebook.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Upgrading to a new version is always risky, so it is a good idea to have a good backup of the previous system before starting such an adventure. One of the things, that is done by the upgrader is to disable PPAs and non-standard repos. **Now you can enable them** if you wish (and if they are available for 18.04), in order to install the program packages, that you want (and that reside in PPAs and non-standard repos).

Comment: is there an easy and quick way to check the PPAs that are compatible with 18.04?

Comment: Visit each PPA at **http://launchpad.net** and check, for example [https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages](https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages). Near the top of the page it states "This PPA currently publishes packages for Cosmic, Bionic, Artful, Zesty, Yakkety, Xenial, Wily, Vivid, Trusty, and Precise." Bionic is 18.04 LTS.